# curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 51786: Connection refused

Tags: curl

When i running :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.ph
```

i get the error.

I already reinstall and purge and install curl.
my Apache server is running as well.

Comment: Is the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable set?

Comment: @Ryan J. Yoder how do i check ?

Comment: Try running the following command "echo http_proxy: $http_proxy HTTPS_PROXY: $HTTPS_PROXY $https_proxy ALL_PROXY: $ALL_PROXY $all_proxy"

Comment: Yes i guess there is a proxy : http_proxy: http://127.0.0.1:51786/ HTTPS_PROXY: http://127.0.0.1:51786/ http://127.0.0.1:51786/ ALL_PROXY:

Comment: How can i remove it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, it appears you have a local proxy configured that is not working properly. Fixing the proxy is probably out of scope of this question However you can fix the curl command by `unset`-ing these the proxy environment variables temporarily.

```
$ unset http_proxy
$ unset HTTPS_PROXY
$ unset https_proxy
```

Comment: Thanks for response. that solve the problem but another error raised :curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions to the directory you're running the command from?

Comment: you are right.Thanks

Comment: If this answered your question, would you mind marking it as "accepted".